# Looking for a .fil converter

Tags: database, file, upload, file-type

The short: I inherited a website I didn't make. The previous site (which I have been redesigning) had a file upload feature which converted .docx, .xlsx, .pdf, etc. into .fil and stored them in an uploads folder.

The previous developer is no longer available and I'm looking for a reliable way to convert the files back into their original types/extensions. Any ideas on a reliable conversion application? Or just a simple way to go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd try to just change the file extension to .pdf or .doc and try to open the file with Microsoft Word or Adobe Reader.  If that fails, give opening straight into Word a shot.  I don't think that Word handles that file extension natively, but it may be able to interpret it. Good luck.

Comment: Jeez-- who knew? Yes, the original program will open the converted file. I can't believe there isn't more documentation of that online?? Thanks!